# Website taking too much time to load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser

My website is taking too much time to load. How can I find means to reduce the page load time.

```
http://beta.east-west.world/data
```

The load time on my local machine to quick enough without delays. But once the webpage is released over server it's taking too much time.

As suggested

1. You need to check on your image sizes (if your page contains images). One thing you can do is ensure your image sizes from design are of the size you want it to be on your web page. Shrinking a huge image to match a small div is never a good idea.

   Me : No images are being used.
2. Where are your script files placed? Do you have your javascript on same page as your html? If so, then create a separate javascript file, move your javascript codes in there and reference that file in your html page.

   Me: Javascript are on separate files and referenced on the page.
3. Placing your javascript file references after your html also boost web page loading.

   Me: Most of the js files are placed at the bottom of the html.
4. Do you have CDN files, i.e. javascript files that load from external links? If yes, you should recognize that those files wont load same as your local files would.
5. If your database is hosted on an external server and you're displaying data on your web page gotten from your db, that could also cause some delays if your db server capacity isn't sufficient to service your requests.

   Me: All the data on the page are utilizing the json file.

Comment: try using chrome inspector's network tab. you can see how much time it takes to load resources of your website.

Comment: Try using [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)

Comment: @Icemanind Thanks I just checked the page over this addon , Will try to work it out and thus improve my webpages performance.

Answer (score 0):

there are several causes to a web page's delay in loading.

1. You need to check on your image sizes (if your page contains images). One thing you can do is ensure your image sizes from design are of the size you want it to be on your web page. Shrinking a huge image to match a small div is never a good idea.
2. Where are your script files placed? Do you have your javascript on same page as your html? If so, then create a separate javascript file, move your javascript codes in there and reference that file in your html page.
3. Placing your javascript file references after your html also boost web page  loading.
4. Do you have CDN files, i.e. javascript files that load from external links? If yes, you should recognize that those files wont load same as your local files would.
5. If your database is hosted on an external server and you're displaying data on your web page gotten from your db, that could also cause some delays if your db server capacity isn't sufficient to service your requests.

Comment: It's happening mostly with Microsoft edge browser.